# Как отключить оптимизацию кода в PlatformIO(PIO)?

Tags: c++, gdb

Скачал PIO для того что б кодить в VS code, начал делать отладку вышло сообщение "optimized out" при наведении на
int tick= SystemCoreClock;

Comment: Если оптимизировано, значит скорее всего результат выполнения этой строки никак не используется, и она вообще ничего не влияет. Нужно смотреть код конкретно, чтобы понимать, что вы этой строкой вообще хотели сказать.

Comment: В 99% случаях, если просто тупо написать такую строчку в любую фунцию, компилятор увидит что tick не используется, и выбросит переменную, не зарезервивовав под неё место в стеке/регистрах. Если SystemCoreClock является property или class - то вызов будет. А результат компилятор "потеряет". Если SystemCoreClock - будет переменной типа int - то под эту строчку код вообще сгенерирован не будет. Такую элементарную оптимизацию делают почти все компиляторы.

Comment: Что бы компилятор не убирал tick, добавьте volatile. `volatile  int tick= SystemCoreClock;` Это касается всех компиляторов, не только PIO.